# GET request from a PHP script in a limited environment

Tags: php, http, httpwebrequest

I have to run a get request from a PHP script, but I'm in a fairly limited environment (tight firewalls, can't modify the PHP install, etc...).

fsockopen() returns an error and http_get() seems to not be installed.  The only other way I know of is to call file_get_contents(), which works OK, except for the fact that I need to set the referrer header in the request (which I don't think you can do with file_get_contents().

Does anyone know any other way to run a GET request via php?

Thanks!

**edit**:  also, CURL is unavailable.  :-(

Comment: +1 for a well formed question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the a header using `file_get_contents()` with an [HTTP context](http://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php). For example

```
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
              "Referer: http://foo.bar.com\r\n"
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$fp = fopen('http://www.example.com', 'r', false, $context);
fpassthru($fp);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Thanks Otterfan! I ran across that answer and posted it here about 8 minutes before you :-D - Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

See CURL functions in PHP.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I forgot to add CURL to the list of methods which aren't available.  :-(  Thanks, though!

Answer (score 0):

After some additional research, it looks like my best bet given the resources I have is to use stream_context_create() to create the headers in the context stream, which you can apparently sent to file_get_contents().  Didn't know that!